# How do I trigger HTML5 validation error popup when custom validation message is set manually?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

I have the following code:

```js
document.getElementById('testSubmit').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('test').setCustomValidity('THIS WILL ALWAYS BE AN ERROR, how do I display this message?');
  console.log(document.getElementById('test').validationMessage);
});
```

```html
<input id = "test" type = "email" required>
<input id = "testSubmit" type = "submit">
```

As you can see, I can indicate that an error happens in the input field. However, I would like to display the message in my `input.validationMessage` which is set by `setCustomValidity` method in my error popup (which does not appear). How do I make the UI validation error popup to appear. For reference, the popup I'm referring to can be seen in the following code:

```js
document.getElementById('btn-submit').addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!document.getElementById('form').checkValidity()) {
    document.getElementById("submit-hidden").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form" action="">

  <input type="text" required />
  <input id="submit-hidden" type="submit" style="display: none" />

</form>

<button id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

Which displays the popup 'Please fill out this field' when you submit without filling the field. How do I trigger that popup, but with my custom validation message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so by using the .reportValidity().
Here is an example:

```js
document.getElementById('testSubmit').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('test').setCustomValidity('THIS WILL ALWAYS BE AN ERROR, how do I display this message?');
  document.getElementById('test').reportValidity();
});
```

```html
<input id = "test" type = "email" oninput="validateInput();" required>
<input id = "testSubmit" type = "submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you below code for Customize default validation message, But I have doning for required validation not for other, if you want to do for other validation as well please customize more

**Form Code**

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
    <input type="text" name="b" id="b" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Js Code**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var inp of elements) {
        inp.oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("Change Validation Message");
            }
        };
        inp.oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
```